# SQL query...I need to insert 2 values from same column of table1 to 2 different columns of table2

Tags: mysql, sql

`insert into friends (user_id1,user_id2) 
select user_id from user where UserName='summer'or UserName='winter'`

This gives an error. I want to insert user_id of 'summer' into user_id1 and user_id of 'winter' into user_id2. Please help?

Comment: You need to change your SELECT clause to get that done. Right now, you're just returning one value through your SELECT, which is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select must have same number of columns as insert, therefore:

```
INSERT INTO friends (user_id1,user_id2)
SELECT (SELECT user_id FROM user where UserName='Summer') AS user_id1, (SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE UserName='Winter') AS user_id2
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into friends (user_id1,user_id2) 
select user_id, -1 from user where UserName='summer'

update friends 
set user_id2 = (select user_id from user where UserName='winter')
where user_id2 = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (user_id1,user_id2)
SELECT
  (SELECT UserName
   FROM table1
   WHERE UserName='Summer') AS user_id1,

  (SELECT UserName
   FROM table1
   WHERE UserName='Winter') AS user_id2
```

## [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2c32/1)